# Fittext not working on WordPress Posts

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I am trying to use fittext on the headers on my Worpress posts, but it is not working.

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 textFit">
    <h2 id="fittext1"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">  <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_category(', '); ?>
  </div>    
</div>
```

footer.php (on output, js is brought in through functions - )

`jquery` is brought in through `Wordpress` in the head (enquened in `functions.php`)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/new/js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#fittext1").fitText(1.8, { minFontSize: '90px', maxFontSize: '150px' });
     });
</script>
```

css

```
article h2 > a {    
  font-size: 90px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 85px;
  letter-spacing: -.075em;
  color: #fff;
}

.textFit {
  display: block
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about what result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: please check your js path. Is it correct ?

Comment: Fittext is a jquery/javasript file that allows for large text to be essentially responsive. It scales in size as the screen shrinks/grows. Instead of break points using just jquery. I just want the same effect that they show in their site. http://fittextjs.com (their homepage uses their function)

Comment: the output is taken from the inspector on my browser so that is put in my footer. Jquery is included in the head since I am using Bootstrap 3 CDN

Comment: my <?php the_title(); ?> is in a link in an h2 tag, I want the code to affect that

Comment: updated question with new code based on suggestions but still not working

Comment: Have you checked the brower console tab to confirm that there are not JS error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help because I don't whether its works or not. Just a Suggestion, try this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
    {
     $("#fittext1").fitText(1.8, { minFontSize: '90px',maxFontSize:'150px'});
    });
</script>
```

Check this for additional Info : [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: If this is not working, please let me know which versions you're using for Wordpress and Jquery.

Comment: I'm starting to see some results based on your suggestion, thank you!

Comment: By default the jQuery v1.8.3 is integrated on WordPress 3.5.1 but the 'FixText-Plugin' seems not to work with it. So try switch to jQuery v1.7.2.